# Automate Page Load Performance Testing with Firebug and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, firebug, webdriver

I am using   `firefox12` and downloaded `firebug-1.9.0.xpi` & `netExport-0.5.xpi`, but the har file is not created. Any changes that can be done. Program Code:

```
   class Program 
   {
    public IWebDriver webDriver;
    public InternetExplorerDriver IEDriver;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            try
            {
                profile.AddExtension(@"D:\LoadTesting\firebug-1.9.0.xpi");
                profile.AddExtension(@"D:\LoadTesting\netExport-0.5.xpi");
            }
            catch (IOException err)
            {

            }
            profile.SetPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
            String domain = "extensions.firebug.";
            string output_dir =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            output_dir = Path.Combine(output_dir, "Firebugnetexports");
            if (!Directory.Exists(output_dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(output_dir);
            }

            profile.SetPreference(domain + "currentVersion", "1.8.2");
            profile.SetPreference(domain + "allPagesActivation", "on");
            profile.SetPreference(domain + "defaultPanelName", "net");
            profile.SetPreference(domain + "net.enableSites", true);
            profile.SetPreference(domain + "netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport", true);
            profile.SetPreference(domain + "netexport.showPreview", false);
            profile.SetPreference(domain + "netexport.defaultLogDir", output_dir);
            try
            {

                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.janodvarko.cz");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            webDriver.Quit();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to use [Browsermob proxy](http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/) in conjunction with Selenium. It will allow you to run Firefox without plugins, and to output the har file.  The project has the creator of Selenium on board, and some other well known figures.  The [Github Project](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy) has a sample which shows how to create the Har file, from there you could write your own code to process it and ensure your performance metrics are met, or that your included javascript / css was located, write it to disc, etc...